# Don't have a /locate command in Minecraft (1.7.5)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing Minecraft Java Edition v1.7.5, on Windows Vista.  I started a survival mode game about a week and a half ago.  I have cheats turned on, and can use `/spawn` for example, but I don't have the `/locate` command - if I do, for example `/locate Mansion` it says "Unknown command - check /help for a list of commands" (or words to that effect).

I've checked the list of `/help` commands and it isn't listed there.  Has it been taken out of the game?  I don't even know if i'm playing an up to date version or if it's just the last version that worked on Vista or something.

It's disappointing as I want to go on a quest to find a Woodland Mansion with my son, but it will take too long to wander around and hope we see one - i thought if I had the coordinates then it becomes like some big adventure expedition where we have to travel for days to reach it, which sounds like a lot of fun.

These are the help commands I do have access to:

```
achievement give
clear
debug
defaultgamemode
difficulty
effect
enchant
gamemode
gamerule
give 
help
kill
me
playsound
publish
say
scoreboard
seed
setblock
setworldspawn
spawnpoint
spreadplayers
summon
tell
tellraw
testfor
testforblock
time
toggledownfall
tp
weather
xp
```

Comment: 1.7.5 doesn't include Mansions either, so even if it supported `locate`, you wouldn't find any of them.

Comment: Are you a time traveller? 1.7.5 was the latest version in 2014 and regular support for Windows Vista ended in 2012. On the other hand, woodland mansions and `/locate` were added to the game in 2016. Please tell me you're not currently in the process of messing up the flow of time!

Comment: But seriously, if you're still using Windows Vista, you should switch away from it ASAP, because you're 8 years behind current virus tech and patches against viruses, on a system that was not very secure at its time anyway. Windows 7 is approaching its extended support end as well, Windows 8 is even worse than most Windows versions and Windows 10 already comes preinstalled with spyware, adware, etc., so I recommend switching to a Linux distribution. Ubuntu for example is a user-friendly one for people who are used to Windows. In Minecraft I would recommend updating, but you don't have to.

Comment: I do have Linux on that same machine - I only use Vista in rare situations and I generally prefer not to use Windows.  I had some compatibility issues which meant I couldn't install Minecraft on my Linux installation, but maybe I should try again.  It is an old computer and pretty creaky.  I'm sad to say i'm not a time traveller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/locate` was not added until version 1.11, and it was expanded in 1.13. So no, there is no `/locate` in 1.7.

1.7 is quite an old version.  If you can, you should consider updating Minecraft if possible.

Comment: thanks.  Do you know, if I reinstalled Minecraft in a newer Windows, would I be able to carry on my Survival game?  Does my world get saved on a server against my account? thx

Comment: No, worlds are not saved on account, they are locally on your computer. Head to `C:\Users\[your username here]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves` on Windows to gain access to all your worlds. Each folder represents a world.  Copy that folder to an external disc/cloud. Then on the new computer, download/copy the files to the same folder on the new computer!

Comment: thanks - would that work if transferring from Windows to Linux?

Comment: Linux location: `~/.minecraft/saves/`. You can copy the folder into there.